# How to add a class for this section

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

Hi I have working on wordpress site, but I need to add a `class` to a `DIV` section. But directly I could not access that `DIV` section. So I need to add a `class` using jquery. Below is my code

```
<div class="et_pb_code et_pb_module  et_pb_code_0">
 <div class="form-container"> 
  <form>
   Below come form code..........
  </form> 
 </div>
</div>
```

This is the design of form [picture](http://prntscr.com/gjm9b9)
so I need to add a class next to `form-container`

Comment: where u want to add a class here

Comment: add what you have tried also posting a link to an image is not good practice because people will not go to an external link just to check the image

Comment: @guradio thanks for your reply dude and knowledge .cool

Answer (score 0):

Use [`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method:

```
$('.et_pb_code .form-container').addClass('your-desired-class');
```

> `.addClass( className )`
>   Adds the specified class(es) to each element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can select an element by class. So if you want to add a class to the external div you could use

```
$('div.et_pb_code.et_pb_module.et_pb_code_0')
```

Then just use addClass as normal.